# Why am I receiving this exception when calling a native C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, unmanaged, dllimport

My .NET 4.0 application needs to call an unmanaged C++ compiled DLL.  I have the C# wrapper for the DLL.

When I include the C# wrapper in a console application and call the first method of DLL, the code crashes.  If I check "Allow unmanaged code debugging" under project properties, it works fine.

When I add that same C# wrapper in my WCF REST based application (hosted on IIS), the code starts crashing right away.  It crashes even if I run the IIS process under the Administrator group of the machine.  Why don't I see any "Allow unmanaged code debugging" in the project properties of my WCF project?

Here is the Exception received in VS:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x05b65db0 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

Why is this is happening when all the DLL files are in the proper places?

Comment: Can you run that DLL from a console application? If so, then maybe that DLL doesn't understand running in a service. It may assume a desktop environment: single user, no threads, no reentrancy.

Comment: is your p/invoke code correct?  the debugger *may* be adding extra padding to the native code hence it works fine during debug sessions.

Comment: I think that first you should figure out why it crashes in the console application before you add the complexity of a WCF REST service. What exception do you get when it crashes in the console app?